# Bash, need to count variables, round to 2 and store to variable

Tags: bash, variables, integer

I need to count variables, round to 2 and store to variable.

Example:

I have variable from array ${array[5]} and vat variable defined, I need to calculate simple

```
( $vat * ${array[5]} + ${array[5]} )
```

and store to variable pricevat.

I tried:

```
vat = 0.21

pricevat=$(echo "$vat * ${array[5]}" + ${array[5]} | bc -l)
(( pricevat=$vat*${array[5]}+${array[5]}))
```

But nothing works:

```
line 48: ((: pricevat=0.21*0.233+0.233: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".21*0.233+0.233"
```

Could you help me please? Where is the problem? What is best solution for this. Thank you very much.

S.

Comment: `((...))` can't do floating-point arithmetic, which is the source of the error. The previous line works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is working! I did it like this.

Arithmetic operations:

```
pricevat=$(echo "$vat * ${array[5]}" + ${array[5]} | bc -l)
```

Round to 3 places:

```
pricevat=$(printf "%0.3f\n" $pricevat)
```

If there is another way to do it better or together on one line, let me know please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On possibility (though, it will not *round*, but *truncate* to 3 decimal places):

```
array=( ... ... ... ... ... 102.03 ... )
vat=0.21
pricevat=$(bc <<< "scale=3; (1+$vat)*${array[5]}")
```

The trick is to have `bc` do the rounding, using its special variable `scale`, set to `3`.

Comment: Did you already try: `mkfifo fifo;exec 7> >(exec stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 bc -l >fifo);exec 6<fifo ;rm fifo` then `echo >&7 "scale=3;(1+$vat)*${array[5]}";read -u 6 -t .01 result`... So you could ask for many operation using `FD7` and `FD6` (keeping `scale=3` as long you don't change them;)...